# Deriving new dataframe from a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1 that looks like this:

```
  Z1  Z2  Z3 Z4
   0   0   A  A
   0   B   0  0
   C   0   C  0
   D   0   D  0
   0   0   E  0
```

I want to make a new dataframe df2 that looks like this:

```
  Z1  Z2  Z3 Z4
  C   B   A  A
  D       C  
          D  
          E
```

For that I am declaring a blank dataframe `df2` which has column  `Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4`.
I am doing so with the help of for loop which is as follows:

```
periods=['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3', 'Z4']

for i in periods:
    for j in range(0,len(df1)):
        if df1.loc[j:j,i:i]!=0:
           #I want to write such that non zero value will be written in df2
           #Like
           #df2[something]=df1.loc[j:j,i:i]
```

But the length of `df2` is 0 as of yet, and so I can't access its cells by indexing, and I am not able to sort out how to put values into `df2`.

Note:This question is different from the one marked as duplicate my explanation for same is in comments

Comment: There I wanted to filter the dataframe.Here I am deriving a new dataframe becuase filtering was not working for me.So I dont think it would be a duplitcate

Comment: You cannot have variable column lengths in a dataframe. You were told this in your last question! If a row is present, it must have a value (or NaN or "" or whatever) for each column. If you absolutely insist on going down this route, perhaps a dictionary is more suited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k: pd.Series(list(filter(None, df[k]))) for k in df}).fillna('')

#   Z1 Z2 Z3 ZR
# 0  C  B  A  A
# 1  D     C   
# 2        D   
# 3        E   
# 4
```

This may be more efficient than `lambda` for larger dataframes.

Comment: This works but it rearranges the column in my new dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need ?

```
df.replace('0',np.nan).apply(lambda x: sorted(x,key=pd.isnull)).dropna(thresh=1).fillna('')

Out[681]: 
  Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
0  C  B  A  A
1  D     C   
2        D   
3        E
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using `pd.DataFrame.apply` with `pd.Series` + a list comprehension:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in x if i != '0']))

#     Z1   Z2 Z3   Z4
# 0    C    B  A    A
# 1    D  NaN  C  NaN
# 2  NaN  NaN  D  NaN
# 3  NaN  NaN  E  NaN
```

If you'd rather have empty strings than`NaN`, add a call to `.fillna`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in x if i != '0'])).fillna('')

#   Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
# 0  C  B  A  A
# 1  D     C   
# 2        D   
# 3        E
```

Comment: This isn't bringing any change to the original dataframe.When I run this in console i get output as it is

Comment: @Rookie_123 I ran this both on 2.7.10 and 3.6.2, and it works as expected for both versions. If you want to make a change to `df` in-place, then obviously you need to assign it back to `df`, i.e. `df = df.apply(...)`, otherwise the change isn't stored. If none of the above applies, then check your `dtypes` -- when I copy your example `df`, all of the column `dtypes` are `object`, as I expect they would be for you too.